# Examples of tangent vectors (or vector fields) with values in a vector space (or vector bundle)

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Consider following two definitions:

> **Definition 1.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $p\in M$ and assume that $V$ is a
>   real vector space. We will say that a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map
>   $w:C^\infty(M)\to V$ is a tangent vector at $p$ with values in $V$ if
>   for any $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$ $$w(fg)=f(p)w(g)+g(p)w(f).$$

And we can generalize it to the global objects.

> **Definition 2.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifolds and assume that $E$ is smooth vector
>   bundle over $M.$ We will say that a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map
>   $W:C^\infty(M)\to \Gamma(E)$ is a vector field with values in $E$ if
>   for any $f,g\in C^\infty(M)$ $$W(fg)=fW(g)+gW(f).$$

I think this is a very natural generalisation of tangent vectors and vector fields.

> **Question.** Are there any examples of tangent vectors/vector fields with values in vector bundles which arises in the differential geometry?

Obviously except when $V=\mathbb{R}$ or $E$ is a trivial 1-dimensional vector bundle $M\times\mathbb{R}.$ I am interested if such objects appear in riemmanian, or symplectic, or poisson, or any other geometry.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) is quite general, and encompasses also the definitions you have stated. One particularly fruitful example in differential geometry is the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)
$$d:C^\infty(M)\to \Omega^1(M)$$
taking smooth functions to [differential one-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) on the manifold. In the terms of your definition 2, the vector bundle $E$ in this case is the cotangent bundle $E=T^*M$ of the manifold.